# Compiz - Cannot easily drag window from top

Tags: xubuntu, compiz, window-manager

On Xubuntu 18.04 (New install today) and Compiz, I have an irritating problem that occurs with maximized windows. From the top, there appears to be a ~4px border that is part of the window (Alt+Drag DOES work) but not part of the title bar (Dragging doesn't work)

[image]

Comment: It seems like the problem is that Compiz is trying to "resize" the window from the top ~4 pixels. Still no idea how to fix this.